# Switching between components in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, components, browserify

I want to create a simple flow, with 2 components. The first component is rendered, I click a button on it and this action render the second component. Clicking on the button from the second component, it should switch back to the first one, but instead, an error occurred:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined,
>   boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a
>   ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of
>   `exports`.warning @ react.js:20728ReactElementValidator.createElement
>   @ react.js:9853t.exports.React.createClass.render @
>   bundle.js:1ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext
>   @ react.js:6330ReactCompositeComponentMixin._renderValidatedComponent
>   @ react.js:6350wrapper @
>   react.js:12868ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @
>   react.js:6303ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @
>   react.js:6287ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @
>   react.js:6216wrapper @
>   react.js:12868ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   react.js:6164ReactReconciler.performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   react.js:13667runBatchedUpdates @ react.js:15356Mixin.perform @
>   react.js:17245Mixin.perform @ react.js:17245assign.perform @
>   react.js:15313flushBatchedUpdates @ react.js:15374wrapper @
>   react.js:12868Mixin.closeAll @ react.js:17311Mixin.perform @
>   react.js:17258ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @
>   react.js:8842batchedUpdates @
>   react.js:15321ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent @ react.js:10336
>   react.js:20250
>
> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. Check the render method of
>   `exports`.invariant @ react.js:20250instantiateReactComponent @
>   react.js:18268ReactCompositeComponentMixin._updateRenderedComponent @
>   react.js:6312ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate @
>   react.js:6287ReactCompositeComponentMixin.updateComponent @
>   react.js:6216wrapper @
>   react.js:12868ReactCompositeComponentMixin.performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   react.js:6164ReactReconciler.performUpdateIfNecessary @
>   react.js:13667runBatchedUpdates @ react.js:15356Mixin.perform @
>   react.js:17245Mixin.perform @ react.js:17245assign.perform @
>   react.js:15313flushBatchedUpdates @ react.js:15374wrapper @
>   react.js:12868Mixin.closeAll @ react.js:17311Mixin.perform @
>   react.js:17258ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @
>   react.js:8842batchedUpdates @
>   react.js:15321ReactEventListener.dispatchEvent @ react.js:10336

First component:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Second = require('components/second/view.jsx');

module.exports = React.createClass({

handlerClick: function () {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Second />,
        document.getElementById("app-container")
    )
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <input type="button" value="COMPONENT 1" onClick={this.handlerClick} />
  )
}
});
```

Second Component:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var First = require('components/first/view.jsx');

module.exports = React.createClass({

handlerClick: function () {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <First />,
        document.getElementById("app-container")
    )
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <input type="button" value="COMPONENT 2" onClick={this.handlerClick} />
  )
}
});
```

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <First />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("app-container")
);
```

Comment: no need to add the whole error message and you can also clean up your question to be more specific otherwise no one can help.

Answer (score 10):

You only ever call `ReactDOM.render()` when you mount the application. Once mounted, you never call `ReactDOM.render()` again on the same mount point. [*see update below.]

Remember that your view is a function of your props and state. To change your view, trigger a change in state.

I suggest something like this:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: 'FIRST'
        };
    },

    handleClick: function () {
        var active = this.state.active;
        var newActive = active === 'FIRST' ? 'SECOND' : 'FIRST';
        this.setState({
            active: newActive
        });
    },

    render: function () {

        var active = this.state.active;

        return (
            <div>
                {active === 'FIRST' ? (
                    <First />
                ) : active === 'SECOND' ? (
                    <Second />
                ) : null}
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Toggle
                </button>
            </div>
        );

     }

});
```

And make the Parent the root node. i.e.

```
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

**UPDATE:** I've since learned you *can* call `ReactDOM.render()` [multiple times on the same mount point](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/691301224541503488). This would typically be in the same place you initialise the application. Nevertheless, you certainly don't call `ReactDOM.render()` from inside a React component.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a very simple solution creating a `SwitchComponents` component:

```
// SwitchComponents.js:

import React from 'react';

export default function SwitchComponents({ active, children }) {
  // Switch all children and return the "active" one
  return children.filter(child => child.props.name == active)
}
```

And import it in your app:

```
// App.js
import SwitchComponents from './components/SwitchComponents';

export default function App() {

const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState("questions")

return (
    <SwitchComponents active={activeComponent}>
      <Home name="home" />
      <Instructions name="instructions" />
      <FileboxContainer name="filebox" />
      <Questions name="questions" />
    </SwitchComponents>
  )
}
```

Comment: Brilliant :) I've never thought about filtering children's props

Comment: here is the updated version for typescript import { ReactElement } from "react";

export default function SwitchComponents({ active, children } : {active: string, children: ReactElement[]}) : ReactElement
{
  return children.filter((child: ReactElement) => child.key === active)[0];
}

Answer (score 2):

**Hooks version (React 16.8+):**

Minimal version.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(true);
  const toggleChecked = () => setToggle(toggle => !toggle);
  return (
     <div>
        {toggle && <First /> }
        {!toggle && <Second /> }
        <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleChecked}>
           Toggle
        </button>
     </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the render function ternary operator will be replaced simply and the full answer will be like:

```
    /** @jsx React.DOM */

    var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            active: 'FIRST'
        };
    },

        handleClick: function () {
            var active = this.state.active;
            var newActive = active === 'FIRST' ? 'SECOND' : 'FIRST';
            this.setState({
                active: newActive
            });
        },

        render: function () {

            var active = this.state.active;

            return (
                <div>
                    {(active === 'FIRST') && <First /> }
                    {(active === 'SECOND') && <Second /> }
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        Toggle
                    </button>
                </div>
            );

         }
    });


  ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app-container'));
```

Rest will be same.